# Why does SQL Server return 0 for  ISDATE('13/01/2010')

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a view where I have a column having date in varchar formet and in `dd/MM/yyyy` 
when I tried to use order by it gives error that

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

The query is

```
select * from test1.dbo.abcd order by CONVERT(date,ddate,103)
```

Some dates on which it return 0 is `13/01/2010`

```
18/12/2009
20/10/2009
21/06/2010
19/10/2009
18/11/2010
29/10/2009
29/10/2009
18/03/2010
15/03/2010
15/03/2010
15/03/2010
15/04/2010
15/04/2010
15/04/2010
15/04/2010
30/03/2010
14/05/2010
14/01/2010
23/10/2009
20/10/2009
27/10/2009
27/10/2009
20/07/2009
20/04/2010
13/08/2010
30/06/2011
23/07/2010
27/08/2010
24/09/2010
```

Can any one tell me why its returning 0 and how to sort it?

Comment: Why isn't your date stored as a `DATE` type?

Comment: the datetime functions vary *vastly* between database systems. If this is just about SQL-Server, please remove the `plsql` and `mysql` tags.

Comment: What happens if you just convert on the dates with issues?

Comment: it is sql server 2008 R2

Comment: it is a view from other table which i cant modify

Comment: Is the data you show from the actual query - its is not sorted by date and does not include the string you say is in error (also what does the title have to do with the question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this works fine for me:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,'13/01/2010',103);
```

Try:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(ddate, 10), 103);
```

What I suspect has happened is that the data pushed into your view has trailing characters that you can't see (e.g. carriage returns) or non-printing characters. You can check for values that exceed 10 characters by:

```
SELECT ... WHERE LEN(ddate) > 10
```

If that still doesn't work, then perhaps the data really is bad, e.g. maybe it is:

```
13/O1/2010
```

In which case the only thing you can really do is push back on the owners of the table/view to get correct data in the first place, or try to filter out using:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

...
WHERE ISDATE(ddate) = 1
```

As for the title in your question, `ISDATE` returns 0 in that case because by default that's not a date - in most cases SQL Server is set up using US English  and a date format of MDY, therefore it expects date strings in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. `13/01/2010` is the first day of the 13th month in 2010. My memory is sketchy but I am certain there wasn't a 13th month that year.

As others have suggested, the real fix for this is to store your data as date/time, not strings, and to pass in string literals in an unambiguous format, e.g. `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: i have tried that but does not work also one thing i just notice that all the dates on which it returns 0 is date greater then 12

Comment: if i try 07/12/2011 or 10/01/2012 it returns true

Comment: @Vikky ISDATE is not going to return 1 for 13/01/2010 unless you `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`.

Comment: it affect whole database, is there no table specific way?

Comment: @Vikky it only affects your session - where did you learn that it affects the whole database?

Answer (score 4):

`set dateformat dmy` might sort it out

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the problem is the use of `ISDATE()` function and not the `CONVERT()`.

You can try this one:

```
ISDATE( CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(date, ddate, 103) ) )
```

but I can't find a reason to do this check with `ISDATE()`. The above will be dependant on the 
`DATEFORMAT` setting (and maybe other settings I'm not aware off) and it will fail with errors, when the `CONVERT()` function finds incompatible dates.

---

Perhaps the best hack you can do, **if you can't convert the dates to `DATE` dataype, which should be stressed as the best thing to do in any case when you are dealing with dates**, is to check with this:

```
ISDATE(SUBSTRING(ddate, 7, 4) + SUBSTRING(ddate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(ddate, 1, 2))
```

Comment: `SELECT ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, '13/01/2010', 103)));` yields 0 for me.

Comment: It fails, oddly enough, if `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have added that it depends on the settings. And it will fail with errors (during the `CONVERT()`) when there are dates that have incompatible format.

Comment: Yeah I still think that everything on this page is a hack. The fix is to store the data correctly in the first place. You should never have to check `ISDATE()` on a date you've stored in SQL Server. Ever.

Comment: thanks for your help aoron and  @ypercube. Both of you are really great in logic.

Answer (score 0):

13/O1/2010 is translated by default US date formats as the first day of the 13th month and thus not a valid date.